# Data binding in XtraGrid control

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xtragrid

I want to bind a datasource in `XtraGrid` control but I am not able to do it. The problem is that I have created columns in `XtraGrid` at design time and I am binding records at run time using a user defined collection.

I created four columns in the `XtraGrid` at design time. First one is a `CheckBox` type, second and third one is `Default` and last one is `Button` type.

I created a structure in my program:

```
public struct Test
{
      public bool IsSelect{get; set; }
      public string First{get; set; } 
      public string Second {get; set;}
}
```

Then I created a `List<Test>` collection which contains 10 Test type record. 
For binding I wrote the following code:

```
grid1.DataSource = userList;
```

Now I want to bind this record in XtraGrid control. `IsSelect` property should be bound with the `CheckBox` column and the remaining two properties will bind with the second and third columns.

Is it possible in XtraGrid?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET Framework 3.5 and C# language.

Answer (score 0):

the XtraGrid is not a standard .NET control but a Developer Express Control...we use them where I work and have found their support line to be very responsive, their website is www.devexpress.com.

That being said, I would think that as long as the FieldName of the columns match the names of the fields within your structure this should work fine.

-Hollis

Answer (score 0):

The column fieldname should be set to the objects property fieldname.  Once you've added columns in the designer they won't be created automatically anymore.

Read more about it here:
Traditional Data Binding Methods
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2387

Binding Controls to Data Created at Runtime
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2387